# Visual Studio 2013 // f = fopen_s("text.txt", "r") - doesn't work

Tags: file, visual-studio-2013

I know of two ways of using fopen:

1. fopen_s(&f, name, mode);
2. f = fopen_s(name, mode);

the first one works in visual studio 2013
the second one does not, i get an error stating:

Error: a value of type "errno_t" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "FILE"

The code should either find a file and print on screen the number in the file or exit the code, when I use the first option `fopen_s(&f, "text.txt", "r");` the code goes directly to the NULL. The file is there in the default folder.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
int n;
FILE *f;

f = fopen_s("text.txt", "r");

if (!f)

{ 
        printf_s("\nError reading file");
        exit(1);
}

else

{ 
    fscanf_s(f, "%d", &n);
    printf_s("The file contains no: %d", n);

    fclose(f);
}

_getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the second way to use it is incorrect.  fopen_s does not return a FILE *.  On the other hand, fopen works the way you think the second version does.   Your choices are `fopen_s(&f, "text.txt","r");` or `f = fopen("text.txt","r");`